# PDFBox PDDocument add a pdf-layout Document?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am getting familiar with the flavors out there for PDFBox. I would like to know if there is a way to get pdf-layout elements into a PDDocument object. the pdf-layout elements use Document as the parent and PDFBox use PDDocument as parent.

```
PDDodcument doc = new PDDocument();
Paragraph someText = new Paragraph();
Frame shape = new Frame(someText);
//Im looking for something like doc.add(shape);
```

Libraries used:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/examples.html
&
https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout

- org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
- rst.pdfbox.layout.elements.Frame
- rst.pdfbox.layout.elements.Document

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Turns out that you have to make the `rst.pdfbox.layout.elements.Document` 
 the parent i.e:

```
Document ParentDoc = new Document();
Shape rec = new rec(10);
ParentDoc.add(rec);
//ParentDoc.getPDDocument()... use for PDFBox Items
```